# Has been blocked by CORS, Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request

Tags: javascript, python, flask, cors, flask-cors

I try to make a connected light with a raspberry pi 0 W and a Pimoroni mood light.
the goal is to control the light (color and brightness) from a website on a web server who is not my raspberry pi.

To make this, I use :

1. a flask web server to receive all the requests to change the color,
2. the unicorn package for the LEDs
3. a web server with a web page who you can control the color (just a html page)
4. a javascript script who fetch the raspberry pi
5. a raspberry pi tunnel to access securely my raspberry pi from the internet

and when i use my website, the website says :

`Access to fetch at 'https://link.to.my.raspberry.com/color' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

this is my flask web server :

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
import unicornhat as unicorn
unicorn.set_layout(unicorn.AUTO)
unicorn.rotation(0)
unicorn.brightness(0.4)
width,height=unicorn.get_shape()
app = Flask(__name__)   # Flask constructor

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html");

@app.route("/color", methods = ["POST"])
def setColors():
    print(request.form)
    red = request.form["red"]
    green = request.form["green"]
    blue = request.form["blue"]
    brightness = request.form["brightness"]
    print(red)
    print(green)
    print(blue)
    unicorn.set_all(int(red), int(green), int(blue))
    unicorn.brightness(float(brightness))
    unicorn.show()
    return ('', 204)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
    app.run(debug = True)
```

this is my local website (home.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello !</h1>
        <form action = "/color" method = "POST"> 
            <p><h3>Enter LEDs color</h3></p> 
            <p><input type="range" id="red" name="red" min="0" max="255" step="1" style="width: 200px;"></p>
            <p><input type="range" id="green" name="green" min="0" max="255" step="1" style="width: 200px;"></p>
            <p><input type="range" id="blue" name="blue" min="0" max="255" step="1" style="width: 200px;"></p>
            <p><input type="range" id="brightness" name="brightness" min="0" max="1" step="0.1"></p>
         </form>
    </body>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```

and here is the javascript file :

```js
let pitunnel = "https://my.link.to.my.raspberry.com"
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", async function apiFetch(params) {
            let red = await document.getElementById("red").value;
            let green = await document.getElementById("green").value;
            let blue = await document.getElementById("blue").value;
            let brightness =  await document.getElementById("brightness").value;
            const response = await fetch(pitunnel + "/color", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({red : red, green : green, blue : blue, brightness : brightness})
            });
        })
```

**It should be noted that I've tried to use this file home.html and it worked, bit i want a instant update, not a button to click :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Bonjour !</h1>
        <form action = "https://my.link.to.my.raspberry/color" method = "POST"> 
            <p><h3>Enter LEDs color</h3></p> 
            <p><input type="range" name="red" min="0" max="255" step="1" style="width: 200px;"></p>
            <p><input type="range" name="green" min="0" max="255" step="1" style="width: 200px;"></p>
            <p><input type="range" name="blue" min="0" max="255" step="1" style="width: 200px;"></p>
            <p><input type="range" name="brightness" min="0" max="1" step="0.1"></p>
            <p><input type = 'submit' value = 'mettre'/></p> 
         </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```